# Rails find_by_sql issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following call in my RoR script:

```
Foo.where("event = 'Login'").group('user_id').order('user_id ASC').count()
```

This gives me a list of all users and how much they have logged in in the form of:

```
<userid1> => <count>, <userid2> => <count>, ...}
```

This is great and very close to what I wan but I've been unable to convince it to sort by the count of logins instead, what I'd really like to have it do. There is also a column that has some info about the login session in the form of a character delimited string. I'd like to get at certain parts of that information.

To achieve this I've tried using find_by_sql and when I make the following call:

```
Foo.find_by_sql("SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS number, SUBSTRING_INDEX(stuff, ',', 1) AS info FROM <table> WHERE event = 'Login' GROUP BY userid")
```

What I get is a ilst of Foo entries that contain the userids but not the count or the info. When I run this in the MySQL workbench it works like a charm. Is there something else I need to do to get this to work? Also, would there be a way to just do this using Foo.select or Foo.where? Thanks.

**Update** I have also tried this format, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499767/ruby-on-rails-count-and-group):

```
Foo.find(:all, :select => 'count(*) count, userid', :group =>'userid')
```

But this too merely responds with the userids and does not spit out the count.

**Update 2** Looking at the output a bit more i can see now that when i do the find_by_fql call everything is being found in the correct way and even being sorted. It just isn't actually selecting the COUNT(*) or the SUBSTRING_INDEX.

**Update 3** I also tried out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057166/convert-sql-query-to-ruby-help) SO tip but when I tell it:

```
Foo.find(:all, :select => 'userid, count(*) as cnt', :group => 'userid')
```

It doesn't print or find anything related to the var cnt. I'm totally baffled here because I've seen more than one example now that does it this ^^ way and I've yet to get it to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your problem is not an SQL problem.  To generate the correct SQL you would just need this:

```
Foo.where("event = 'Login'").group('user_id').order('count_all').count()
```

Take a look in your log and you'll find that this generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, user_id AS school_id FROM `foos` GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count_all
```

...and if you run that in your SQL console you'll get what you want.

The **problem** is that Rails doesn't return them in this order, Rails **always** returns these special `group/count` results in the order of the `GROUP BY` field.  So, if you want them in a different order then you'll need to do it in Ruby after getting the hash back.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks so much. Is there a way I could add this to the select as well? SUBSTRING_INDEX(stuff, ',', 1) AS info

Comment: You'll have to switch to doing a `select()` clause like @Ed suggests below in order to get any field other than the count and the group field.

Answer (score 0):

Code below returns an array of foos, checking any element inside foo will return userid/cnt

```
foos = Foo.find(:all, :select => 'userid, count(*) as cnt', :group => 'userid')
```

Is this what you're looking for?

```
foos.first.userid # will show userid
foos.first.cnt # will show count
```